# Error while trying to import data from mysql to cassandra using sqoop

Tags: java, mysql, cassandra, sqoop, cassandra-cli

I installed DSE and set the path in .bashrc and sqoop-env.sh.
Fisrt I ran dse using the command

```
cd dse/bin

sudo sh dse-env.sh
```

then I started the job tracker and task tracker process using the command

```
~/dse/bin/dse Cassandra -t
```

I tried importing  database person.empl,to an already created empty column family emp of the keyspace comp using the command

```
~/dse/bin/dse sqoop cql-import --table empl --cassandra-keyspace comp --cassandra-table emp --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/person --username root --password root --cassandra-host 127.0.0.1 -m 1
```

but I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.<init>(IIIIIZ)V
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Frame$DecoderV1.<init>(Frame.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Frame$Decoder.<clinit>(Frame.java:162)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$PipelineFactory.getPipeline(Connection.java:1029)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:212)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:99)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:573)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:244)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:190)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1230)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:157)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:245)
    at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqoopUtil.setCqlImportOptions(SqoopUtil.java:146)
    at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.CqlImportJob.configureOutputFormat(CqlImportJob.java:79)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:240)
    at com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.SqlManagerAdapter.importTable(SqlManagerAdapter.java:236)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:57)
```

Version of nettyjar present in Cassandra/lib is 4.0.23 and in Cassandra/tools/lib is 3.9.0

Can somebody help to resolve this?

Comment: What version of DSE did you try this on? Also, what path information did you set in .bashrc and sqoop-env.sh?

Comment: The version of dse installed is 4.7.0 Path information set in .bashrc :#Sqoop
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/sqoop
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin

#cassandra
export PATH=$PATH:/home/bdsa/dse/resources/cassandra/bin

Comment: Also JAVA_HOME ,hadoop_home(ie the path where bin/hadoop is available) and hadoop path , In sqoop-env.sh: Set path to where bin/hadoop is available ie ,Set path to where hadoop-core.jar is available